# What are the possible errors or exceptions while drawing any Google chart?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-visualization

My resent task is to list all the errors or exception I will get while using any Google Chart in MVC. I know "Table has no Columns" and "Undefined is not a function"
So please help me to list them.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering would it really help to know all possible exceptions or errors. There might be plenty of those. Why would you care?

It all depends on a particular chart and its usage.

Anyways I am afraid its a tedious task and if you really have to do it, you will have to dig the Google APIs. For a basic list, you can search on [Google API](https://developers.google.com/search/results?q=Exception%20classes&p=%2Fchart)

Comment: Yes, Its tedious task but anyhow I have to do it.